# List view is blank in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

Hi guys I am developing this app for android 4.3 and below it's an sms blocking app. I am using one activity and rest are fragments. Right now I have two list fragments one is blacklistfragment that is appearing normally but other blockedlistfragment is blank. I set some break points and data is loading in adapter but no output from fragment there are no errors so I am troubled here. Would be great if some one can point out what I am doing wrong or what is missing :)

These are my files:

====BlockedlistFragment.java===

```
package com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.adapters.BlockedListArrayAdapter;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data.BlacklistData;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data.Blockedlist;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data.BlockedlistData;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shahz on 8/22/2016.
 */
public class BlockedListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment{
    List<Blockedlist> blockedlist;
    public BlockedListFragment() throws SQLException {

        blockedlist = new BlockedlistData().getBlockedlist();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container.removeAllViews();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blockedlist, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Log.d("SHAHZ","finally yarr");



            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        BlockedListArrayAdapter adapter = new BlockedListArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.blockedlist_listitem,
                blockedlist);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Blocked Status: ","It is started now");

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("Status: ","It is stopped now...");
//        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadBlacklist();
    }
}
```

===BlockedlistArrayAdapter.java===

```
package com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.MainActivity;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.R;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data.Blockedlist;
import com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data.DBHandler;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shahz on 8/24/2016.
 */
public class BlockedListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blockedlist>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Blockedlist> objects;
//    DBHandler db;

    public BlockedListArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Blockedlist> objects) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
//        db=DBHandler.getInstance(this.context);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final Blockedlist blocklist = objects.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blockedlist_listitem, null);
        TextView textBlockedId=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blocked_id);
        textBlockedId.setText(blocklist.getBlockedId());
        TextView textBlacklistId=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blacklist_id);
        textBlacklistId.setText(blocklist.getBlacklistId());
        TextView textMessageCount=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_count);
        textMessageCount.setText(blocklist.getBlockedCount());
        TextView textBlockedName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blocked_name);
        textBlockedName.setText(blocklist.getContactName());
        TextView textBlockedNumber=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blocked_number);
        textBlockedNumber.setText(blocklist.getBlacklistNumber());
        Log.d("shahz",blocklist.getBlockedId());
        Log.d("shahz",blocklist.getBlacklistId());
        Log.d("shahz",blocklist.getBlacklistNumber());
        Log.d("shahz",blocklist.getBlockedCount());
        Log.d("shahz",blocklist.getContactName());
//        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Log.d("Blocked message : ",String.valueOf(blocklist.getBlockedCount()));
////                ((MainActivity)context).loadEditContactFragment(blocklist.getId(),blacklist.getName(),blacklist.getNumber());
//            }
//        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

===BlockedlistData.java===

```
package com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shahz on 8/25/2016.
 */
public class BlockedlistData {
    private Cursor result;
    private List<Blockedlist> blockedlist= new ArrayList<Blockedlist>();

    public List<Blockedlist> getBlockedlist() {
        return blockedlist;
    }

    public BlockedlistData() throws SQLException {
        DBHandler handler=DBHandler.getInstance(null);
        handler.removeExpiredMessages();
        result = handler.getBlockedList();

        if(result!=null && result.moveToFirst()){
            do {
//                count=handler.getBlockedCount(Integer.valueOf(result.getString(1)));
                blockedlist.add(new Blockedlist(result.getString(0),result.getString(1),result.getString(2),result.getString(3),result.getString(4)));
                Log.d("Results are: ",result.getString(0)+" "+result.getString(1)+" "+result.getString(2)+" "+result.getString(3)+" "+result.getString(4));

            }while (result.moveToNext());

        }
        result.close();
    }
}
```

===Blocklist.java===

```
package com.studio.shahz.ultimatesmsblocker.data;


import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by Shahz on 8/19/2016.
 */
public class Blockedlist{

    //  constants for field references
    public static final String BLOCKED_ID="1";
    public static final String BLACKLIST_ID = "count";
    public static final String BLACKLIST_NUMBER="number";
    public static final String CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String BLOCKED_COUNT="50";

    //  private fields
    private String blocked_id;
    private String blacklist_id;
    private String blacklist_number;
    private String contact_name;
    private String blocked_count;


    //  getters and setters
    public String getBlockedId(){
        return blocked_id;
    }
    public void setBlockedId(String id){
        this.blocked_id=id;
    }
    public String getBlacklistId(){
        return blacklist_id;
    }
    public void setBlacklistId(String id){
        this.blacklist_id=id;
    }
    public String getBlacklistNumber(){
        return blacklist_number;
    }
    public void setBlacklistNumber(String number){
        this.blacklist_number=number;
    }
    public String getContactName(){
        return contact_name;
    }
    public void setContactName(String name){
        this.contact_name=name;
    }
    public String getBlockedCount(){
        return blocked_count;
    }
    public void setBlockedCount(String count){
        this.blocked_count=count;
    }

    //  Used when creating the data object
    public Blockedlist(String id,String blacklistId,String number,String name,String count) {
        this.blocked_id=id;
        this.blacklist_id=blacklistId;
        this.blacklist_number=number;
        this.contact_name=name;
        this.blocked_count=count;
    }

    //  Create from a bundle
    public Blockedlist(Bundle b) {
        if (b != null) {
            this.blocked_id=b.getString(BLOCKED_ID);
            this.blacklist_id=b.getString(BLACKLIST_ID);
            this.blacklist_number=b.getString(BLACKLIST_NUMBER);
            this.contact_name=b.getString(CONTACT_NAME);
            this.blocked_count=b.getString(BLOCKED_COUNT);
        }
    }

    //  Package data for transfer between activities
    public Bundle toBundle() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(BLOCKED_ID,this.blocked_id);
        b.putString(BLACKLIST_ID,this.blacklist_id);
        b.putString(BLACKLIST_NUMBER,this.blacklist_number);
        b.putString(CONTACT_NAME,this.contact_name);
        b.putString(BLOCKED_COUNT,this.blocked_count);
        return b;
    }

    //  Output flower data
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return contact_name;
    }

}
```

Plus the query I am using to fetch data is below. It works and can log data in adapter from this:

```
public Cursor getBlockedList(){
        Cursor result;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query="SELECT b.id, b.blocked_id, l.phone_number,l.contact_name,count(b.id) " +
                "FROM blockedmessages b, blacklist l WHERE b.blocked_id = l.id GROUP BY b.blocked_id";

        result=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return result;

    }
```

THANKS for your time :)

Comment: why are you calling this: `container.removeAllViews();` also move all adapter initialisation out of `onCreate()` and into `onViewCreated()` - before the listView `onClickListener()`

Comment: use a RecyclerView

Comment: I think the main problem is the `BlockedListArrayAdapter` when you call `super(context, resource)` in the constructor without the `List objects` you need to implement the `int getCount()` method. Or you call the `super(context, resource, objects)` instead.

Comment: Because I am using SharedPreferences and using two kinds of fragment managers so they come overlapping each other that's why using contianer.removeAllViews();

Comment: Quallenmann thanks your solution works. Lol that's why I love coding I am up for this list two nights from now and here it is :P